# Javascript Image Slider - Problems/Tweaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay so this is a two part question.

1. I am using the Slicebox image slider (located here http://tympanus.net/Development/Slicebox/index.html ) on my website, but I need to make so it automatically plays.
2. Unfortunately the cool 3D effects are less than good on IE, so I also need to make it so that the effect changes to just fade (or something of that sorts) on IE.

The java script for my website is located here:  http://www.757stylist.com/Slicebox/js/jquery.slicebox.js

Thank you for your time and consideration for reading and/or responding to my question.

Comment: Code please. We are not psychic.

Comment: It is in the link above.  Here it is since you just skimmed through it.  http://www.757stylist.com/Slicebox/js/jquery.slicebox.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1, you need to override the default option `autoplay : false`:

```
$('#sb-slider').slicebox({
    autoplay : true
});
```

Question 2 is ambiguous since there is no option for this within the scope of slicebox (perhaps consider using an alternative slider framework) as this does not support IE at all:

[image]

Comment: Silly me, I just skimmed through and didn't even see the autoplay function in it.